# Resolved url not working while posting a share in linkedin page

Tags: java, spring, rest, linkedin-api

I am trying to post a share with entity location and resolved Url in content entities, Even though i am pointing resolvedUrl to a image, it is not considering that image instead fetching 'og:image' from entity location. I don't see any use of resolvedUrl.

Suggest on how to use resolvedUrl ie. image with custom url.

Body:

```
{
    "owner": "urn:li:organization:xxxxxxx",
    "distribution": {
        "linkedInDistributionTarget": {}
    },
    "content": {
        "contentEntities": [{
            "entityLocation": "https://www.cricbuzz.com/cricket-news/107673/ipl-2019-rishabh-pant-shikhar-dhawan-propel-delhi-capitals-to-the-top-rr-vs-dc-rajasthan-royals",
            "thumbnail": [{
                "resolvedUrl": "https://www.cricbuzz.com/a/img/v1/595x396/i1/c168531/watson-led-csks-chase-of-176.jpg"
            }]
        }],
        "description": "Description of attachment",
        "title": "Title of the attachment"
    },
    "text": {
        "text": "Hii Kaushik from builder"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello I think it might be because of a typo: It should be "thumbnails" instead of "thumbnail", see if it works.

Link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/share-api#post-shares

```
{
    "owner": "urn:li:organization:xxxxxxx",
    "distribution": {
        "linkedInDistributionTarget": {}
    },
    "content": {
        "contentEntities": [{
            "entityLocation": "https://www.cricbuzz.com/cricket-news/107673/ipl-2019-rishabh-pant-shikhar-dhawan-propel-delhi-capitals-to-the-top-rr-vs-dc-rajasthan-royals",
            "thumbnails": [{
                "resolvedUrl": "https://www.cricbuzz.com/a/img/v1/595x396/i1/c168531/watson-led-csks-chase-of-176.jpg"
            }]
        }],
        "description": "Description of attachment",
        "title": "Title of the attachment"
    },
    "text": {
        "text": "Hii Kaushik from builder"
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.